# Problem with send method in Infura

Tags: web3js, infura, web3js-v1.x

Newly Infura site has been changed its interface.

Before that all methods of our client program was successfully working, but now when I logon to Infura, all whitelists has been removed. I added our contract addresses to  it, then `.call` method is working proper, but unfortunately `.send` method is not working.

How can I solve this problem? Do you have any similar experience?

P.N: I am using web3.js v1.0.0

Comment: I had got email saying they are changing their API endpoints.. So just to double confirm you are using correct Infura end point?  https://blog.infura.io/infura-dashboard-transition-update-c670945a922a

Comment: Can you provide an example of the error you are receiving when trying to send?  The whitelist changes should in no way effect sending of transactions.  Are you sure you are signing the transaction on your end, as we do not support signing the transaction on our end (since we do not have your private keys).